# join() Not Removing Commas from Array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to complete a Kata whereby I create a phone number from a given array input.

`Input`: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]

`Output`: (123) 456-7890

The issue I have is that once I have built my string, when I call `join('')`, the commas are not being removed. My results is still: `(1,2,3) 4,5,6-7,8,9,0`.

What is the issue with the code that is preventing this happening?

```
function createPhoneNumber(numbers){
  var newNum = [];
  newNum.push("(" + numbers.slice(0,3) + ")" + " " + numbers.slice(3,6) + "-" + numbers.slice(6,10));
  return newNum.join('');
}
```

Comment: Works for me  https://jsfiddle.net/u3fpo429/

Comment: I also cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: yup works for me too with input string "1234567890"

Comment: Sorry guys, the numbers param was an array. I'll update the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the `numbers` parameter is an *array*:

```js
function createPhoneNumber(numbers) {
  var newNum = [];
  newNum.push("(" + numbers.slice(0, 3) + ")" + " " + numbers.slice(3, 6) + "-" + numbers.slice(6, 10));
  return newNum.join('');
}
console.log(createPhoneNumber('1234567890'.split('')));
```

In which case `.slice`ing it will produce another array, from the specified indicies, and using `+` with an array will result in concatenation. When the array gets implicitly turned into a string, its elements will be joined by a comma.

Join the sliced array while concatenating instead (and don't create a `newNum` array):

```js
function createPhoneNumber(numbers) {
  return "(" + numbers.slice(0, 3).join('') + ")" + " " + numbers.slice(3, 6).join('') + "-" + numbers.slice(6, 10).join('');
}
console.log(createPhoneNumber('1234567890'.split('')));
```

A nicer option would be to join the `numbers` into a string first:

```js
function createPhoneNumber(numbers) {
  const numStr = numbers.join('');
  return `(${numStr.slice(0, 3)}) ${numStr.slice(3, 6)} - ${numStr.slice(6)}`;
}
console.log(createPhoneNumber('1234567890'.split('')));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recomment that you use `template literals` introduced in `es6`:

```
function createPhoneNumber(numbers){
  const phNo = `(${numbers.slice(0,3)}) ${numbers.slice(3,6)}-${numbers.slice(6,10)}`
  return phNo
}

createPhoneNumber('1234567890') // output ==> (123) 456-7890
```